# Should the website automatically save on logout

Tags: user-expectation, save

We have a website where user needs to fill out a long application form.

Currently when the user navigates through the different pages of the form, we automatically save their progress and the user has access to a save button on every page.

The user is able to log out and log in at any time.

Question is, should the site automatically save the page when user clicks logout? What would the user expect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you have stated it, that your form comprises of many pages. Hence your user needs to be made aware that their progress will be saved or put in draft state if they logout.

> You should provide user with a model dialog when he/she clicks on
>   logout. The model dialog will ask the user whether they want to save
>   their changes or discard their changes. After selecting any on these
>   actions, user will automatically logout.

Comment: Thank u, i implemented in above way.